# Making a bash script executable from everywhere in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've had quite a lot of trouble getting my script (ironically called "script.sh") to run everywhere. I've followed lots of guides and videos on the internet, but I cannot get it running. I've tried doing chmod u+x script.sh while it being in /usr/bin, either way it won't work.

It keeps on saying "scrips.sh is not an executable file".

The script is as follows:

```
    #!/usr/bin

# Command Options
headname=unlac.net
commandenabled=true
commandname=main
version=0.0.1
author=a-human
servername=ulctesting
server=ulc-testing
guideref=none


if [ $commandenabled = false ]; then
        echo "\e[4m\e[1mErr: ULC-001, Command Disabled.\e[0m"
else
if [ $1 = help ]; then
         echo "\e[2m=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[$headname]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\e[0m"
         echo "\e[7mㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ ㅤㅤㅤ ㅤHelp System * ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ\e[0m"
         echo "Coming Soon"
else
if [ $1 = ver ]; then
        echo "\e[2m=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[$headname]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\e[0m"
        echo "\e[7mㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤSystem Versionㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ\e[0m"
        echo "Coming Soon"

if [ $1 = guide ]; then
        echo "\e[2m=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[$headname]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\e[0m"
        echo "\e[7mㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤSystem Guides ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ\e[0m"
        echo "Welcome to the system guides for $headname. Please refer to the online guides"
        echo "which are listed on the given manual document for the system found on the"
        echo "provided url: \e[4mhttps://unlac.net/guide/manual/ \e[0m Please note that"
        echo "we try our very best to update this and add sections per server and system."
        echo "\e[1mGuide Ref:\e[0m\e[2m $guideref\e[0m\e[1m Server Name\e[0m\e[2m $server\e[0m"
else
        echo "\e[2m=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[$headname]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\e[0m"
        echo "\e[7mㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤWelcome, $USERㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ\e[0m"
        echo "\e[1mULC Version:\e[0m \e[2m$version | \e[1mAuthor:\e[0m \e[2m$author"
        echo " ______ "
        echo "| |__| |   \e[1m(C) $author, all rights reserved.\e[0m"
        echo "|  ()  |   \e[1mFor the use of $headname only, please read the\e[0m"
        echo "|______|   \e[1mulc-net system guide for more information.\e[0m\n"
        echo "\e[7mㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤChange Logsㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ\e[0m"
        echo "\e[100m05/04/2022 by root,\e[0m\e[1m Welcome to the ULC Systems!\e[0m"
        echo "Cheese"
fi
fi
fi
fi
```

I gave it the function to be able to be disabled, etc. Anyways, whenever I run the script e.g. sh script.sh, it works but when I do it trying to let it run everywhere in Ubuntu, it just won't.

Comment: Your shebang looks incorrect...

Comment: Check the very first line of the script; that line is the *shebang* @mook765 is referring.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` should help!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, you also probably need to wrap the `$1`s in quotation marks `"$1"`, and add `-e` after the `echo`s to allow for the escape sequences to work properly.

Comment: How the shebang works is documented in [the execve manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man2/execve.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing line 1 from `#!/usr/bin` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

That first line tells your shell what program to run the file with. Right now it is telling the shell to use the directory `/usr/bin`.

Since `/usr/bin` isn't a valid interpreter you'll get this error.

```
script.sh: /usr/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

> Note that the `Permission denied` error message is about `/usr/bin` not your script.

The reason why `sh script.sh` worked is because you were providing script as an argument to a valid interpreter.

To avoid issues like this I recommend installing `shellcheck` and running it against your scripts regularly. It has saved me from lots of silly mistakes.